# How can I define a color for a user in a chat

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I have a chat with pusher, it's working well, but now I would like to change the color of your own username when you are talking. At the moment, my username et the username of another user is in black, but I would like to have the username of your own account in another color to know when you are talking. (My english is kinda medium sorry ask if you need more explanation)
Thanx for helping

This is in my app.blade

```
    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div class="panel-body panel-content" id="mess_cont">

                                    <chat-messages id="mess" :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <chat-form
                                            v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                                            :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"
                                    ></chat-form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my ChatMessages.vue :

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat messages" >
        <li class="left clearfix list-group-item" v-for="message in messages" >

        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font" >
                        {{ message.user.firstName }}
                        {{ message.user.lastName}}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ message.message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messages']
    };


</script>
```

Comment: Can't help you unless you show how your `messages` and `Auth::user()` are structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `User` model has some sort of `id`, you could apply CSS classes or styles based on the id of the author of the message.
It could be something like this

```
<chat-messages id="mess" :messages="messages" :currentuserid="{{Auth::user()->id}}"></chat-messages>
```

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat messages" >
        <li class="left clearfix list-group-item" v-for="message in messages" >

        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font "  
                            v-bind:class="{
                                classForAuthorSameAsUser: (message.user.id === currentuserid),
                                classForAuthorDiffThanUser: (message.user.id !== currentuserid)
                            }">
                        {{ message.user.firstName }}
                        {{ message.user.lastName}}
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <p>
                    {{ message.message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messages','currentuserid']
    };


</script>

<style scoped>
.classForAuthorSameAsUser {
  color: red;
}
.classForAuthorDiffThanUser {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thx a lot dude it's actually working, it's been a while since I try to do this !!